# Passing object through React-Router v5 Link

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to pass objects(`chartData`) through `react-router Link`
So I tried like this :

## App.js

```js
<Switch>
  <Route path="/csvFile" exact component={CsvFilePage} />
  <Route path="/csvFile/:id" component={CsvFilePage} />
</Switch>
```

### SettingMenu

(there is `Link` in here and I'd like to pass `chartData` to CsvFilePage)

```js
const SettingMenu = ({ show, chart, chartData }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Setting show={show}>
        <Box>
          <Link
            to={{
              pathname: `/csvFile/${chart.key}`,
              state: {
                chartData: JSON.stringify(chartData),
              },
            }}
          >
            <InsertDriveFileIcon style={{ fontSize: 40 }} />
            <p>csv</p>
          </Link>
        </Box>
      </Setting>
    </>
  );
};
```

here is the `CsvFilePage`

## CsvFilePage

```js
const CsvFile = ({ match }) => {
 
 return (
 <div className="preview">
   {match.params.id === "Bar" && chartType[0]}
   </div>
 }
```

I searched about it and I tried to use it but I have no idea how to get the state from `Link`.
and i could get `params.id`  but i don't know how to get objects so I tried to get objects as same way as i did for getting id but i didn't work

and the `chartData` data looks like this:

```js
{
    labels: defaultLabels,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "dataSetting",
        data: defaultDatas,
        backgroundColor: defaultBackgroundColor,
      },
    ],
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your state is inside `location` https://reactrouter.com/web/api/location

Thats how you can get it:

```js
const CsvFile = ({ match, location }) => {
 const { chartData } = location.state;
 return (
 <div className="preview">
   {match.params.id === "Bar" && chartType[0]}
   </div>
 }
```